# How to add values to multiple lookup field in SharePoint using UpdateListItems

Tags: sharepoint, office365, spservices

I need to add multiple values (ID fields of another custom list) to a **Multiple Lookup** field using **Sp-services**. 
What is the correct format of the data to be used ?
I have tried like ( 5,9,6 ) but only selecting the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it.

```
// "list1Id" contains the array of LIST1 ID fields that you want to add...
// "MULTIPLELOOKUPFIELD" is the multiple lookup field in the LIST2...

var multipleLookupValue ="";
for(i = 0; i < list1Id.length ; i++)
{
    multipleLookupValue = multipleLookupValue + list1Id[i]+";#data;#";
}

var method = "UpdateListItems";

$().SPServices({
    operation: method,
        async: false,  
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "LIST2" ,
        valuepairs: [["MULTIPLELOOKUPFIELD",multipleLookupValue]],
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 

                //alert("Added new item to LIST2 list");                                            
            }

});
```

May be it will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why do you want to do this, because these items you will add - they can't be saved as values, because there is a relationship between the column and lookup list, i.e. if you have Lookup column to the List1 and you add a new value from the List2 with id 99 and save, it will save the reference to the list item with id 99 in the List1.

but if anything, it is possible, this is how I am appending multiple lookup selected values:

```
    var lines = additionalTechnologies.split(';#');

    $.each(lines, function (index) {
        if (lines[index].length < 3) {
            $("select[title='Additional Technologies selected values']:first").append("<option value=" + lines[index] + " title=" + lines[index + 1] + ">" + lines[index + 1] + "</option>");
            $("select[title='Additional Technologies possible values'] option[value=" + lines[index] + "]").remove();
        }
    });
```

and remove them from the all items list. just do it vice versa.

Comment: Actually I need to add **List1** ID field values to **List2** multiple Lookup column.                                                                                                             
I can retrive List2 Lookup field data. But I dont know how to add multiple values (multiple List1 ID field) to Lookup column?

Comment: then the code above doing exactly the thing you need.

Comment: But I need to **Update** that field in List2

Comment: ok. you need to show you code here. how do you update list item? From where you want the code to be run?